# toggle all the next siblings of tr upto next tr not having a class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table like this

```
<table>
<tr class="a"></tr>
<tr class="a b"></tr>
<tr class="a b"></tr>
<tr class="a b"></tr>
<tr class="a"></tr>
<tr class="a b"></tr>
<tr class="a b"></tr>
<tr class="a b"></tr>
</table>
```

Now I want that If I click `<tr>` with class only "a" its siblings hide until it finds next  with class only "a".

So If I click first `<tr>` then the next 3 `<tr>` with also class "b" should hide or show (toggle)
not the `<tr>` which come after next `<tr>` having class only "a"

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `:not()` selector can be used to exclude `.b` for the click event.  Within the click event the same selector can be used in combination with the `nextUntil` function.

Until you make the html valid though, by adding `<td></td>` tags I'm not sure anything will work.

```
$(".a:not('.b')").click(function(){
   $(this).nextUntil(".a:not('.b')").hide();
});
```

**Working Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/sCdHg/

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$("tr.a:not(.b)").click(function(){
  $(this).nextUntil(".a:not(.b)").hide()
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$("tr.a").click(function(){
  $(this).siblings("tr.a.b").hide()
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('tr.a').not('.b').click(function() {
    $(this).nextUntil('tr.a.b').toggle();
});
```